# Connect to GitHub or my VM host using SSH failed on Windows 10

Tags: windows, github, ssh, ssh-keys

key pair been generated by:

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C myEmail@github.com
```

in ~/.ssh/myKey and add myKey.pub on my github account

add it to agent:

```bash
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/myKey
ssh -vvvT git@github.com
```

Git Bash output:

```
OpenSSH_8.8p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/adam/.ssh/config
debug1: /c/Users/adam/.ssh/config line 8: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/c/Users/adam/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/c/Users/adam/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "github.com" port 22
debug3: resolve_host: lookup github.com:22
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to github.com [20.205.243.166] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 4 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: connect to address 20.205.243.166 port 22: Permission denied.
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Permission denied.
```

my config file in ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host 192.168.57.10
  HostName 192.168.57.10
  User root
# Github
Host github.com
User git
HostName github.com
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myKey
```

> The begin of all these crashes is yesterday while I'm coding on VScode with SSH to my VM host(192.168.57.10). all things are good until I reboot my laptop and lunch Git Bash, I tried to test connect GitHub with SSH, failed, regenerate keys, restart SSH service but none of it works. I don't no why :(

SSH to my VM host by VScode Remote Window is the same :

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.57.10 port 22: Permission denied
> 过程试图写入的管道不存在。
[13:41:53.040] "install" terminal command done
[13:41:53.041] Install terminal quit with output: 过程试图写入的管道不存在。
[13:41:53.041] Received install output: 过程试图写入的管道不存在。
[13:41:53.041] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[13:41:53.041] Resolver error: Error: 
    at f.Create (c:\Users\adam\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.76.1\out\extension.js:1:586041)
    at t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\adam\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.76.1\out\extension.js:1:584693)
    at t.tryInstall (c:\Users\adam\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.76.1\out\extension.js:1:681846)
    at async c:\Users\adam\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.76.1\out\extension.js:1:644486
    at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\adam\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.76.1\out\extension.js:1:647831)
    at async t.resolve (c:\Users\adam\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.76.1\out\extension.js:1:645565)
    at async c:\Users\adam\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.76.1\out\extension.js:1:722872
[13:41:53.044] ------
```

so how to handle it, any config wrong? I've been trapped this problem for two days SOS.